# Setting the Template property on a UserControl is not supported

Tags: c#, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I want to make a UserControl which can be used like the example below, however I don't know how to implement that. I found that example somewhere on WPF but seams like this is not supported anymore?

I get following error "WinRT information: Setting the Template property on a UserControl is not supported."

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test.Gui.Widgets.WidgetFrame"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="100" Foreground="AntiqueWhite">This is a Test</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Using the control

```
<local:WidgetFrame>
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Green">Content Presentation</TextBlock>
</local:WidgetFrame>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by looking into other github repos

Seperate xaml and cs file

WidgetFrame.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="using:Test.Gui.Widgets">
    <Style TargetType="local:WidgetFrame">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="100" Foreground="AntiqueWhite">This is a Test</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Add it to the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Gui/Widgets/WidgetFrame.xaml"/>
            <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other app resources here -->

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

WidgetFrame.cs

```
internal class WidgetFrame : ContentControl
{
    public WidgetFrame() { }
}
```

Now I can place the content with xaml without overwriting the template

```
<widgets:WidgetFrame Width="200" Height="200">
    <Button>Yes!</Button>
</widgets:WidgetFrame>
```